# $\sigma(f(A))=f(\sigma(A))$ when $f$ is a suitable rational function

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

> Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbert space. Given
> a rational function $f$ which has no poles inside $\sigma(A)$, show that
> $\sigma(f(A))=\{f(\lambda)\mid\lambda\in\sigma(A)\}$.

If $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$ then take $v\neq0$ s.t. $Av=\lambda v$. Then by linearity $f(A)v=f(\lambda)v$, so $f(\lambda)$ is in the spectrum of $f(A)$. It follows $\sigma(f(A))\subset f(\sigma(A))$.

However, I am struggling with the reverse inclusion, starting with $\lambda\in f(\sigma(A))$.

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from the holomorphic functional calculus? $f$ agrees with a holomorphic function on the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am not familiar with holomorphic functional calculus

Comment: In your proof, it is in general not true that $Av=\lambda v$, in the infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @eigenvalue: that's a very appropriate username in this context! ;)

Comment: First you should tell us what definition of $f(A)$ you are using if you are not familiar with holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: @MaoWao if $f=P/Q$, where $Q(z)=\prod(z-\lambda_i)$ say, then $f(A)=P(A)\cdot\prod (A-\lambda_i I)^{-1}$.

Comment: You should edit that into your question together with a definition of the spectrum, as you seem unclear about that concept (see eigenvalue's comment).

Comment: @Meowdog: evaluating an operators on polynomials and reciprocals of polynomials does not require functional calculus. And OP wrote a definition a few comments ago.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you are right, sorry, i misread

Comment: @dancm I can give you a hint; Observe the expression $f(A) - \lambda =  \left(P(A)-\lambda \prod (A-\lambda_i I)\right) \prod(A - \lambda I)^{-1} =: F(A)\prod(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \in\mathbb{C}$. Note that $F(A)$ is another polynomial. Write $F$ down in factored form and check when $f(A) - \lambda$ is not invertible. This should give you a spectral value $\mu$ for $A$. Prove $f(\mu) = \lambda$. This argumentation helps you for both directions.